# What's Going On With TimeToShine and almostSharepointMaster?

Tags: discussion

Both of their accounts are suspended... (again?)

What's going on with that?

Flame-war amongst the redcoats?

Serial down-voting?

Too much complaining on meta?

I know it's probably none of my business, but I'm as curious as a kid who finds his dad's adult reading material stash for the first time.

Comment: Don't want no no drama drama.

Comment: this was my first time my account got suspended and realy annoyed about it as nothing was made into somthing.... but im happy its over and im moving on to help the community and saying clear from all the drama :)

Comment: Actually, I think it was TimeToShine's second if I'm not mistaken (pretty sure that's how I learned timeouts existed...). But I appreciate your sincerity and look forward to seeing you on the site.

Comment: ... ok, just to know, who of the two is the Horde and who the Alliance? Trad: just make peace. Now. We need both.

Comment: is this wow lol, i am nither! ;) i have made peace and want to be a good community contributor. I thought all was ok untill today :( but alas i will carry on answering questions and hopfully the admins can see that i am mutual :) but if my life was on the line and i had to choose i would go with horde ;) but i myself dont play wow but rather gears of war :)

Comment: @almostSharepointMaster - Look, I would have said "Chaos" and "Orders" ala Ultima Online (or Smurfs VS PinkPanthers as we used to say on our servers because of the coloring of pg names) but since WoW is more widespread (since no one seem to consider selling anything else-at least where I live) you got that. Anyway - please, don't restart the war. I am not sure to have a full understanding of the situation, but I know I tend to vote answers based on their content, non because of the following comment chain. if a comment don't make sense, ignore it or report it. If it make sense, improve

Comment: and no need to say that since I don't know the situation, I won't take any side. It just make me sad to see 2k users with gold medals fighting for nothing. Or there is a give away for the first top N users comming up soon and @KitMenke told me nothing again???

Comment: yup and im not disagreeing with you here, im actually agreeing with you :). I want to stay away from the drama but he goes and starts commenting on my answers that is irrelivant (dragging me back in) which i DONT want! hence why i havent replied back to him and flagged it but i dont want to be penailsed for it tho :( plus i am not starting any war!! and is that a joke about giving the top n users?

Comment: @almostSharepointMaster, pretty sure the N users thing was a joke.

Comment: lol i think so too :P

Comment: I was refering to the 2012 swag - (of which I never understood who was included). So yea, it was a joke. Not that I will get angry if they really want to send me an unicorn plush with the SharePoint logo on the side.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist: No plushies; some SPSE stickers and a SPSE t-shirt, I seem to remember. You can have the stickers if you want... As long as you're not Johnny Foreigner. ;) Postage to to Foreign Lands gets a bit pricey.

Comment: @StuartPegg -_-' so no way to obtain the Unicorn Clippy Deluxe Limited Edition plush? Not even a Lifesize Puyon Beard Replica action figure?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist: Nope. Not unless there were higher tiers of rewards.

Comment: @StuartPegg No SharePoint site should go without an Unicorn Clippy Deluxe Limited Edition plush giveaway. We must therefore perform another swag for the first two page of top users, or the site honor will be forever tainted (to all evil people with no faith in others - there is no way I am suggesting this only because I am in the first two pages, it is only your evilness that make you think so. You should be really ashamed and send me a plushie to make up for it)

Comment: @StuartPegg - [found it](http://www.thinkgeek.com/product/f29f/?pfm=_featured_f29f_4). Now we just need to ask them to make it available in a version with the unicorns colors matching the office logo. (Disclaimer - just joking- I had to post that link after finding it. And no, please, no, for all what's is good in the universe no- I do NOT want that).

Comment: @SPArchaeologist: Mmmm... Unicornicles. Unicornipops? Lollycorns?

Comment: @StuartPegg - actually, I cleary remember that in a cartoon I saw somewhere there was an unicorn with a choco horn which would re-grow everytime somebody ate it (like a magical vending machine). Don't remember where though... maybe Adventure Times (or Guru Guru??).

Comment: lol, I didn't know until now this kind of discussions also take place in Meta! So you guys making them popular ?? :D

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri, we're all popular here. It's the SharePoint cool kids' club: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQ_eBTkB-rs

Comment: @rjcup3 guys how can one be a part of SharePoint cool kid's club lol... I am fastest growing kid here :P

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri, it was sarcasm. I'm full of it.

Comment: @rjcup3 what kind of sarcasm by the way? And my friends call me sarcastic too, so I guess I too fit in the group ;)

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri I guess ironic sarcasm? No offense intended to anyone, as this applies just as much to myself as anyone else, but being a part of the SharePoint cool kids' club is akin to being the coolest kid in cosplay at Comic-Con. Being popular on here is trivial since it's such a niche site; the dedicated user base can't be that big. Besides, what does being popular matter? Plus it gave me the opportunity to link some old school Screeching Weasel. Also, I think a claim like "fastest growing kid here" is hard to make. You: 1year, 6mos - 3,147 rep. Me: 11mos - 3,016 rep. Just saying lol.

Comment: @rjcup3 you actually looking from the time I created the account, but since I have been active this 3,147 is just for several months! You can see Weekly/Monthly reports, they should give you better idea :P... Well I guess than I need to be popular first and than should ask for group entry!

Comment: What happened to alisharepoint this time? banned again?

Comment: Apparently so... it really is a shame... people take reputation points too seriously...

Comment: I noticed his answer to my meta question about 'separate answers on separate questions' was deleted. He was a bit rude and defensive about my response to his answer, but i dont know if that was the cause.

Comment: @mike dont worry your not that important ;) , joking! it had nothing todo with you! I didnt mean to sound defensive or rude what so ever towards you. Its hard to show emotion in text so its easy to think someone is upset ;) , i was banned becasue of one post that i answered that also timetoshine answered lol crazy, if i knew he answered i wouldnt of answered but the mods think otherwise!

Comment: @Mike, Don't worry, I still love you (and appreciate your importance to this community). ^^^ Was a little harsh... Keep up the edits! It's an uphill battle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. They couldn't keep their hands to themselves so they each got a timeout.

I would encourage everyone on the site to be professional. I hope both of them take the time to cool off and come back ready to help people with SharePoint questions.

Comment: that i am :) and it was a shame and annoying that it got to that level as a professional and that is all im going to say about that and im happy to answer questions and stay clear of timetoshine or any other member except if they are genuine than ill be more than happy to help to the best of my ability :)

Comment: on the main stack meta there is a recurring discussion running "make voting public". I am starting to think we need instead to make the full user anonymous. No names == no wars.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist, I don't think this is an issue for most users. More of a bad apple situation http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/02/the-bad-apple-group-poison.html

Comment: @rjcup3, actually I was refering to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164007/votes-history-in-the-answers-feature-request/164009#comment477543_164009 . This idea keeps apperaring on meta, and made me point out that maybee the opposite would end this once and for all.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist, I understand. My input was more directed at "the obvious solution" Jeff Atwood proposed. Worst case scenario of course. Most users don't have an issue playing well with others, but if a few bad apples continually cause problems, there is an "obvious solution" to prevent the bad apples from ruining the whole batch.

Comment: @rjcup3 Yes, understood that. I was only suggesting to solve the problem by removing apples, so worms won't find anything to eat ^_^. We are programmers - always find the solution that requires less code :P. Trad: wasn't really serious there, just trying to cool down some spirits.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist on the upside, this question appears to be pretty popular on meta. Driving traffic!

Comment: lol gossip is allways popular ;)

Comment: Yeah this came into my tweet inbox just, why did I miss the drama.. to much playing around with #sp2013 < and to much twitter...